# Spinner Icon is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, spinner

I would like to display a spinner icon when the user clicks the HTML form submit button and want to hide it when the data is posted to the destination URL. But, In my case, It's not working. Below is the code which I used for this function:

```
function PostData(){

    var validation=false;
    jQuery("#training_submit").prop('disabled', true);

    jQuery('#error_traff').hide();
    jQuery('#error_epost').hide();
    jQuery('#error_fname').hide();
    jQuery('#error_lname').hide();
    jQuery('#error_skola').hide();
    jQuery('#error_grade').hide();
    jQuery('#error_municipality').hide(); 

    var traff= jQuery("#training_traff").val().trim();
    var email= jQuery("#training_epost").val().trim();
    var firstname=jQuery("#training_fname").val().trim();
    var lastname= jQuery("#training_lname").val().trim();
    var phone= jQuery("#training_phone").val().trim();
    var school= jQuery("#training_skola").val().trim();
    var municipality = jQuery("#training_municipality").val().trim();
    var grade= jQuery("#training_grade").val().trim();
    var other= jQuery("#training_other").val().trim();

    if(traff =="") {
        jQuery('#error_traff').show();
        jQuery("#training_traff").focus(); 
    } else if(email =="") {
        jQuery('#error_epost').show();
        jQuery("#training_epost").focus(); 
    } else if(firstname =="") {
        jQuery('#error_fname').show();
        jQuery("#training_fname").focus();
    } else if(lastname =="") {
        jQuery('#error_lname').show();
        jQuery("#training_lname").focus();
    } else if(school =="") {
        jQuery('#error_skola').show();
        jQuery("#training_skola").focus();
    } else if(municipality =="") {
        jQuery('#error_municipality').show();
        jQuery("#training_municipality").focus();  
    } else if(grade =="") {
        jQuery('#error_grade').show();
        jQuery("#training_grade").focus();
    } else{
        jQuery('#loading').show();
        validation=true;
    }

    if(validation==true)
    {
        var user = {
        person_eMail: email,
        person_firstName:firstname,
        person_lastName: lastname,
        company_name: school,
        company_municipality:municipality,
        person_schoolYear: grade,
        person_position: "",
        project_name: "",
        Place: "",
        DeliveryLocation: "",
        person_phone: phone,
        Title: "",
        ReqDelivery: "",
        MeetingName: traff,
        OtherInfo: other,
        PreSchool: false,
        Elementary_Fk6: false,
        FK9: false,
        HighSchool_Other: false,
        Peephole: false,
            FormName:"Pedagogträffsintresse",
            RegisterDate: ""

        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: user,
            url: 'https://example.com/xxxx/xxx/',
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false,
            headers: {'Authorization': 'xxxxx'},
            success: function (result) {
                clearData(); 
                jQuery('#loading').hide();
                jQuery('#training_success').show();
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                $("#training_submit").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });        
    } else {
        jQuery("#training_submit").prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Please look into the code and help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: could you possibly make the indentation of your code something that resembles readable code please

Comment: the other thing is ... this `spinner` is obviously an element with id `loading` ... do you have such an element? who knows, you've shown absolutely no HTML

Comment: Code indented. Please, code with more love next time @.@

Comment: @Ferrmolina, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#maindivIdHERE').on('click', '.buttonClassHERE', function(){
$('#loading').show();
});
```

Insert this code above yours.

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion, but it's not working as expected. Please comment.